# Line is covered by PlotMarkers in ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, legending

Suppose I plot the data and fitting line with black point and red line

```
imgPlotMarkers00 = 
ListLinePlot[{Range[60] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}/2, 60], Range[60]}, 
PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, None}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, 
Joined -> {False, True}]
```

However, I found in the output figure

[image]

the black points cover up the red line. How could I move the red line to the top layer of figure? Is their a option for this?

This is a simple example. In real case I have more than one data-fit line pairs to plot and their legends to placed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to control what goes over what with `Prolog` vs `Epilog` (another way is to use different orders inside `Show` but it is more cumbersome in this case, as it requires to split 1 plot into 2):

```
data={#,#+RandomReal[{-1,1}/2]}&/@Range[40];

ListLinePlot[data,PlotStyle->{Red,Thickness[.01]},
   Prolog->{Black,PointSize[.02],Point[data]}]

ListLinePlot[data,PlotStyle->{Red,Thickness[.01]},
   Epilog->{Black,PointSize[.02],Point[data]}]
```

[image]

If you need `PlotLegends` to work for multiple data you can put lines in Epilog/Prolog and points in `PlotMarkers`:

```
data1={#,#+RandomReal[{-1,1}/2]}&/@Range[40];
data2={#,5+#+RandomReal[{-1,1}/2]}&/@Range[40];

ListPlot[{data1,data2},
    PlotLegends->{"data1","data2"},
    PlotMarkers->{Automatic,Scaled[0.05]},
    Epilog->{{Red,Thickness[.01],Line[data1]},
            {Red,Thickness[.01],Line[data2]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: emm...this is nice..but data in Prolog/Epilog would not show in PlotLegend....

Comment: @Harry You can put your line in `Prolog` and `Epilog`, and depict points with `PlotMarkers`. Then it will shoe up in `PlotLegend` doe multiple data.

Comment: That's a good idea, I can plot points with PlotMarkers, plot line both in  PlotMarkers/None and Epilog, then all thing will show up in PlotLegend!

Comment: @Harry I just added a version of this in the post.

Comment: @Harry and of course on top of that you can still use opacity for any of these components.

Answer (score 3):

> How could I move the red line to the top layer of figure?

May be change the opacity of the black points?

```
imgPlotMarkers00 = 
 ListLinePlot[{Range[60] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}/2, 60], Range[60]},
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, None},
  PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[.3], Black}, Red},
  Joined -> {False, True}
  ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can post-process the `ListLinePlot` output to sort the graphics primitives so that lines come after markers:

```
ClearAll[linesInFront]
linesInFront = SubsetMap[Reverse, #, Join @@ 
   Table[Position[#, {___, {___,  i}, ___}], {i, {_Line, _GeometricTransformation}}]] &;
```

***Example:***

```
data = {Range[40] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}/2, 40], Range[40]};

llp = ListLinePlot[Join[data, 10 + data], 
   PlotMarkers -> {{Automatic, Medium}, None, {Automatic, Medium}, None},
   PlotStyle -> {Black, {Red, Thick}, Black, {Green, Thick}}, 
   Joined -> {False, True, False, True},
   ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLegends -> Automatic];

Row[{llp, linesInFront @ llp}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative/simpler approach: Extract markers and use them as `Prolog`:

```
ClearAll[markersInBack]
markersInBack = Module[{markers = Cases[#, {___,_GeometricTransformation}, All]},
   Show[DeleteCases[#, Alternatives @@ markers, All], Prolog -> markers]]&;

markersInBack @ llp
```

[image]

Comment: This seems a really high level trick....

Answer (score 1):

Put the red line over the black points

```
v={Range[60] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}/2, 60], Range[60]};
Show[
  ListLinePlot[v,PlotStyle->Black,Joined->False],
  ListLinePlot[v,PlotStyle->Red,Joined->True]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Show[ListPlot[Range[60] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}/2, 60], PlotStyle -> Black], 
 ListPlot[Range[60], PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True]]
```

[image]